# Converting a view to Bitmap without displaying it in Android?

Tags: android, bitmap

I will try to explain what exactly I need to do.

I have 3 separate screens say A,B,C. There is another screen called say HomeScreen where all the 3 screens bitmap should be displayed in Gallery view and the user can select in which view does he wants to go.

I have been able to get the Bitmaps of all the 3 screens and display it in Gallery view by placing all the code in HomeScreen Activity only. Now, this has complicated the code a lot and I will like to simplify it.

So, can I call another Activity from HomeScreen and do not display it and just get the Bitmap of that screen. For example, say I just call HomeScreen and it calls Activity A,B,C and none of the Activities from A,B,C are displayed. It just gives the Bitmap of that screen by getDrawingCache(). And then we can display those bitmaps in Gallery view in HomeScreen.

I hope I have explained the problem very clearly.

Please let me know if this is actually possible.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think you won't be able to do that. The problem is that activities are meant to be displayed to the user. You can start the activity and then immediately hide it, but the activity will still be visible to the user for a split-second. It's shown long enough to be noticed so having the screen flicker several times makes the app look unprofessional. However, it might be possible that there is a command to start an activity without displaying it; I just don't know of one if it exists.

Comment: Actually, I was able to do this.

Comment: Oh,how can you call that activity but not to show it?Can I take the current activity's layout as the template to generate  bitmap while feeding different content to it?

Comment: Check answer in this post, i found some kind of solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36424381/save-multiple-textviews-as-image-of-large-resolution/36455437#36455437

Comment: nothing worked for me from above answers. this worked only https://stackoverflow.com/a/26086145/8554111

Answer (score 241, accepted):

there is a way to do this. you have to create a Bitmap and a Canvas and call view.draw(canvas);

here is the code:

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.layout(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```

if the view wasn't displayed before the size of it will be zero. Its possible to measure it like this:

```
if (v.getMeasuredHeight() <= 0) {
    v.measure(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```

EDIT: according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21761151/755804), *Passing `WRAP_CONTENT` as value to `makeMeasureSpec()` doesn't to do any good* (although for some view classes it does work), and the recommended method is:

```
// Either this
int specWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parentWidth, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
// Or this
int specWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0 /* any */, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
view.measure(specWidth, specWidth);
int questionWidth = view.getMeasuredWidth();
```

Comment: I tried this but all I get is a semi transparent black box. Do I need to do something on the view to get it ready for bitmap drawing?

Comment: I actually had to change this to `v.layout(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());` to get this to work correctly, but thanks for the code :)

Comment: I had to use v.getWidth() instead of v.getLayoutParams().width and similar for height. Otherwise, now working.

Comment: I used ````v.measure(0, 0); v.getMeasuredWidth(); v.getMeasuredHeight();````.

Comment: As soon as I call v.measure, my app crashes (view is non-null).

Comment: How do I use it in my Main Activity class?

Comment: `Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);` Works better

Comment: i got this exception 10-26 16:47:23.807: E/AndroidRuntime(24169): java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@425a9728

Comment: This solution will not work in this case:
The View, you are trying to convert, is a layout file and its outermost layout has fixed size and its background image (if set) is larger than the layout size.
In this case, it will generate a bitmap of size of background image.
So in my case, I added on more outer layout and set its size to `WRAP_CONTENT`, and it generated the perfect bitmap.

Comment: I just uses v.getMeasuredWidth() & v.getMeasuredHeight(). In case of v.height & v.width it was getting -1.

Comment: It's not working on TextView, only draw the background, text not draw on the canvas. Any one know how to solve it?

Comment: I couldn't get this to work from a textview.  But I could render the text directly using a Canvas.drawText() call.

Answer (score 36):

here is my solution:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    Drawable bgDrawable =view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable!=null) 
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else 
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return returnedBitmap;
}
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks. I was having problems on some devices if the height was beyond a certain value. I have not tested fully but this appears to resolve that.

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0` nothing to enjoy here :)

Answer (score 31):

I know this may be a stale issue, but I was having problems getting any of these solutions to work for me.
Specifically, I found that if any changes were made to the view after it was inflated that those changes would not get incorporated into the rendered bitmap.

Here's the method which ended up working for my case. With one caveat, however. prior to calling `getViewBitmap(View)` I inflated my view and asked it to layout with known dimensions. This was needed since my view layout would make it zero height/width until content was placed inside.

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutID, null);
//Do some stuff to the view, like add an ImageView, etc.
view.layout(0, 0, width, height);

Bitmap getViewBitmap(View view)
{
    //Get the dimensions of the view so we can re-layout the view at its current size
    //and create a bitmap of the same size 
    int width = view.getWidth();
    int height = view.getHeight();

    int measuredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    int measuredHeight = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

    //Cause the view to re-layout
    view.measure(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
    view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());

    //Create a bitmap backed Canvas to draw the view into
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);

    //Now that the view is laid out and we have a canvas, ask the view to draw itself into the canvas
    view.draw(c);

    return b;
}
```

The "magic sauce" for me was found here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/BxIBAOeTA1Q

Cheers,

Levi

Comment: Cheers! It seems that one must call measure and requestLayout after any changes to the layout for them to be displayed

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I had the same problem. I was using `measure()` and `layout()` before I populated my view so I had strange results. Moving these calls down, above `createBitmap()` fixed it for me!

Comment: how can you know the width and height of view?

Answer (score 24):

Try this,

```
/**
 * Draw the view into a bitmap.
 */
public static Bitmap getViewBitmap(View v) {
    v.clearFocus();
    v.setPressed(false);

    boolean willNotCache = v.willNotCacheDrawing();
    v.setWillNotCacheDrawing(false);

    // Reset the drawing cache background color to fully transparent
    // for the duration of this operation
    int color = v.getDrawingCacheBackgroundColor();
    v.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(0);

    if (color != 0) {
        v.destroyDrawingCache();
    }
    v.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap cacheBitmap = v.getDrawingCache();
    if (cacheBitmap == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "failed getViewBitmap(" + v + ")", new RuntimeException());
        return null;
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(cacheBitmap);

    // Restore the view
    v.destroyDrawingCache();
    v.setWillNotCacheDrawing(willNotCache);
    v.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(color);

    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: How do I use it from my Main activity class?

Comment: This is deprecated

Answer (score 23):

There is a great Kotlin extension function in Android KTX: [`View.drawToBitmap(Bitmap.Config)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/package-summary#(android.view.View).drawToBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap.Config))

Comment: This will not work if the view is not presented in the layout. Error: "IllegalStateException: View needs to be laid out before calling drawToBitmap()"

Comment: Easy and simple. Thanks brother

Comment: I does work if you call `myView.layout(myView.left, myView.top, myView.measuredWidth, myView.measuredHeight)` be sure to call `myView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY))` before that

Comment: @FlavienSi Always black background for circle view. Do you know way to change it ?

Comment: weird answer, what was the point? did you even read the question?

Answer (score 5):

Layout or view  to bitmap:

```
 private Bitmap createBitmapFromLayout(View tv) {      
    int spec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    tv.measure(spec, spec);
    tv.layout(0, 0, tv.getMeasuredWidth(), tv.getMeasuredHeight());
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(tv.getMeasuredWidth(), tv.getMeasuredWidth(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    c.translate((-tv.getScrollX()), (-tv.getScrollY()));
    tv.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```

Calling Method:

```
Bitmap src = createBitmapFromLayout(View.inflate(this, R.layout.sample, null)/* or pass your view object*/);
```

Comment: Thanks for `translate`! It helped me to clip a region in view.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a bit better :

```
/**
 * draws the view's content to a bitmap. code initially based on :
 * http://nadavfima.com/android-snippet-inflate-a-layout-draw-to-a-bitmap/
 */
@Nullable
public static Bitmap drawToBitmap(final View viewToDrawFrom, int width, int height) {
    boolean wasDrawingCacheEnabled = viewToDrawFrom.isDrawingCacheEnabled();
    if (!wasDrawingCacheEnabled)
        viewToDrawFrom.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    if (width <= 0 || height <= 0) {
        if (viewToDrawFrom.getWidth() <= 0 || viewToDrawFrom.getHeight() <= 0) {
            viewToDrawFrom.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            width = viewToDrawFrom.getMeasuredWidth();
            height = viewToDrawFrom.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        if (width <= 0 || height <= 0) {
            final Bitmap bmp = viewToDrawFrom.getDrawingCache();
            final Bitmap result = bmp == null ? null : Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp);
            if (!wasDrawingCacheEnabled)
                viewToDrawFrom.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            return result;
        }
        viewToDrawFrom.layout(0, 0, width, height);
    } else {
        viewToDrawFrom.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        viewToDrawFrom.layout(0, 0, viewToDrawFrom.getMeasuredWidth(), viewToDrawFrom.getMeasuredHeight());
    }
    final Bitmap drawingCache = viewToDrawFrom.getDrawingCache();
    final Bitmap bmp = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(drawingCache, width, height);
    final Bitmap result = bmp == null || bmp != drawingCache ? bmp : Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp);
    if (!wasDrawingCacheEnabled)
        viewToDrawFrom.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    return result;
}
```

Using the above code, you don't have to specify the size of the bitmap (use 0 for width&height) if you want to use the one of the view itself.

Also, if you wish to convert special views (SurfaceView, Surface or Window, for example) to a bitmap, you should consider using [**PixelCopy**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/PixelCopy) class instead. It requires API 24 and above though. I don't know how to do it before.

Comment: Any idea, no TextView is added in bitmap. Only ImageViews are added.

Comment: @Khemraj I don't understand the question.

Comment: It was my fault my TextView was not there in bitmap. Because I had a light color theme applied, thanks for reply.

Comment: @Khemraj Sorry but I still don't understand. All ok now?

Comment: Yes bro, I don't know why you are not getting me :). I had one TextView in layout which I wanted to convert in Bitmap. Layout had one ImageView and one TextView. ImageView was getting converted to Bitmap. But TextView was not appearing in Bitmap. That was problem. After that I realised I had a theme applied that was making TextView text color white. I fixed it. And all okay now. Thanks.

Comment: Will the memory size of created bitmap == view(source view) memory size?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar need and developed something based on codes provided, specially the one by @Azhagthott and the brand new `androidx.core.view.drawToBitmap`, hopefully this will be hopeful here also,

```
import androidx.core.view.drawToBitmap

val view = MyCustomView(context)
view.measure(
    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST)
)
view.layout(0, 0, width, height)
val bitmap = view.drawToBitmap()
```

Comment: it's hardcoded width and height

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps

```
View view="some view instance";        
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap=view.getDrawingCache();
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

**Update**

`getDrawingCache()` method is deprecated in API level 28. So look for other alternative for API level > 28.

Comment: `getDrawingCache` is currently deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I used this just a few days ago:

```
fun generateBitmapFromView(view: View): Bitmap {
    val specWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(1324, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST)
    val specHeight = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(521, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST)
    view.measure(specWidth, specHeight)
    val width = view.measuredWidth
    val height = view.measuredHeight
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    view.layout(view.left, view.top, view.right, view.bottom)
    view.draw(canvas)
    return bitmap
}
```

This code is based in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Rock610/8d64eb2f572558455aef00e2cadd8aba)

Comment: It's help when i have shapofview by florent and it's not working when hardware accelator is true

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun getBitmapFromView(view: View): Bitmap
{
    val returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width,
        view.height
    ,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)

    val canvas = Canvas(returnedBitmap)

    //background image
    val bgDrawable = view.background

    //background image is selected
    if (bgDrawable != null){
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas)
    }
    else{
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE)
    }
    
    view.draw(canvas)
    
    return returnedBitmap

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my project and found a solution, which I will describe here.

```
public Bitmap catchBitmapFromView(View capture_view){
        if (capture_view == null) {
            return null;
        }

        capture_view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(capture_view.getWidth(), capture_view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Drawable bgDrawable = capture_view.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable != null) {
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        } else {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        capture_view.draw(canvas);

        capture_view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Please explain what this does.