# convert view into bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting a view to Bitmap without displaying it in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801116/converting-a-view-to-bitmap-without-displaying-it-in-android)

I am trying to convert the view into bitmap from following reference link

[link text](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/30676.aspx)

Now the problem is how can i get the bitmap that is being converted from view only. in the example author has used relativelayout.dispatchDraw(c) but this line is giving me compile time error i.e.

> The method dispatchDraw(Canvas) from
>   the type ViewGroup is not visible

Here is my code and i have written the following code inside onCreate function

```
    Canvas c=null;

    //Create Layout
    RelativeLayout relativeView ;           
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );

    relativeView = new RelativeLayout(this);            
    relativeView.setLayoutParams(lp);

    //Background of Layout
    Bitmap viewBgrnd  = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.bgblack);
    relativeView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(viewBgrnd));

    //associated with canvas 
    Bitmap returnedBitmap =               Bitmap.createBitmap(320,480,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);     
    c = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();


    //Create Imageview that holds image             
    ImageView newImage = new ImageView(this);
    Bitmap srcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.bgpink);
    newImage.setImageBitmap(srcBitmap);

    TextView newText = new  TextView(this);

    newText.setText("This is the text that its going to appear");       

    c.drawBitmap(viewBgrnd, 0, 0, paint);
            relativeView.layout(100, 0, 256, 256);  
    relativeView.addView(newImage);
    relativeView.addView(newText);


        // here i am getting compile time error so for timing i have replaced this line
        // with relativeView.draw(c);

    relativeView.dispatchDraw(c);
```

Here the returnedBitmap should contain the image of (ImageView and TextView) but this bitmap contains only bacground bitmap of relativeView i.e. bgblack

Comment: I had the same problem former times and found no solution, too. Someone told me, that the drawing cache can be a point. But I wasn't able to get it working in the right way.

Comment: I don't know how to use draw cache

Comment: if i use relativeView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); and after that if i will try to get the cache using relativeView.getDrawingCache() i am getting null bitmap

Comment: yeah -- requestLayout() must be called - but I got always a black bitmap

Comment: i tried requestLayout() but still its not working. Now i am not getting NULL bitmap as i have used relativeView.layout(0,0,10,10) before calling relativeView.getDrawingCache() but the returned bitmap is not showing ImageView and TextView that i have added in to relativeView using addView

Answer (score 28):

here is my solution:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    Drawable bgDrawable =view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable!=null) 
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else 
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return returnedBitmap;
}
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:

```
Bitmap viewCapture = null;

theViewYouWantToCapture.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

viewCapture = Bitmap.createBitmap(theViewYouWantToCapture.getDrawingCache());

theViewYouWantToCapture.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

I believe the view has to be visible (ie. getVisiblity() == View.VISIBLE).  If you are trying to capture it but hide it to the user at the same time, you could move it off screen or put something over it.

Comment: its fine. but how to improve the image quality. while converting the bitmap looks blurred or semi transparent.

Comment: Thanks. It's straightforward method from API: This API can be used to manually generate a bitmap copy of this view, by setting the flag to true and calling getDrawingCache().