# Caption on image in Android

Tags: android, uiimageview

I need to open image in my ImageViwer with Caption which i get from server, I am getting image URL and a text caption. I want a custom image viewer which can display image with Caption.

Image should look like bellow:

[image]

Any help would be appreciable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating your own UI(XML) with ImageView and EditText or textView

Answer (score 0):

Use FrameLayeout  to place Caption on imageview. First take an Framealayout then take one imageview and one textview to place image and Caption . Thanks

Comment: sorry but i do not want to do this, i need something else.

Comment: What you want to do? please clear your post that what you want.

Comment: I am looking for something which behave like same as in built image viewer where i can use pinch zoom in/zoom out and  other things which we can do with Android ImageViewer.

Comment: programmatic way, create a framelayout with imageview and text then convert this framelayout view into imageview view and set it in your image view "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264990/convert-view-into-bitmap"