# Crop to fixed portion of ImageView on Android

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, crop

[image: i want to crop the bitmap that is in the square]

How do i get a part of a `bitmap` (which is in a `imageview`) saved as shown in the picture. All i need to do is to `crop a particular image` using `(x,y)` coordinates. all that i have is `x,y coordinates` and nothing else to select the `cropped area`. Between, user doesnt select the `crop area`. So its enough if its `static`. `yellow part is an imageview(not the whole activity)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just create a new Bitmap and use the original one as the source.
Insert as x and y coordinates 0 and your custom width and hight.
[public static Bitmap createBitmap (Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) .

This post describes how to get a Bitmap from a view, in your case the imageview you want to crop.
[Converting a view to Bitmap without displaying it in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801116/converting-a-view-to-bitmap-without-displaying-it-in-android)

Comment: i tried this, its working. but my problem is i have adapted pinch zoom (multi touch) so i have to crop the zoomed image(only visible part of image) but its cropping the entire image... any idea?

Comment: sorry i don´t have the time right now to write a snippet, but you have to enable the drawingcache for your imageview and extract the bitmap by Bitmap newBitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
i hope this will help you

Comment: I have already tried that. its returning a part of the original image and not zoomed image

Comment: how do you scale the content of the image view?