# How to implement to show multiple titles on android googlemaps

Tags: android, google-maps

When i was trying to display multiple titles(like hello1 and hello2 in code) on google map it shows last title(hello2) only.

Here is my code:

```
  mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
  mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(40.444310, -75.858923))
    .title("Hello1"))
    .showInfoWindow();

  mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(40.303626, -75.592905))
    .title("Hello2"))
    .showInfoWindow();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only show one info window at a time.

"An info window allows you to display information to the user when they tap on a marker. *Only one info window is displayed at a time.* If a user clicks on another marker, the current info window will be hidden and the new info window will be displayed."

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer noted you can't display multiple info windows.

However there are some ways to overcome that. For example override `OnMarkerClickListener` and switch the marker's icon with the popups bitmap.

The popup can also be a view which when drawn can act as your bitmap for the replacement.

However you probably shouldn't meddle too much with google's initial design.

[Here's a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15331983/3249477) with an answer that might help you. Good luck.