# Google maps api v2 show all markers title always without any click

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I need that in my Map-application Google map markers title always will be shown without any user click. I want that this title even will not be possible hide. 
Of course I searched online, and I found this: marker.showInfoWindow(); but it is not working because I have near to 30 markers and I need that all of them will be shown all the time (I guess marker.showInfoWindow(); working just when there is one marker).

............................................................................

(And I would like to know how to do that when map activity will start it will not show whole world from far, but from specific country. I mean already zoomed to this country.)

```
public class Map extends Activity {
static LatLng Sapphire = new LatLng(41.085078, 29.006100);
static LatLng Metrocity = new LatLng(41.076138, 29.010518);
static LatLng Istinye = new LatLng(41.114247, 29.058924); 

private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    try {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        }
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Sapphire).title("Istanbul Sapphire").snippet("Levent")); marker.showInfoWindow();
        Marker marker1 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Metrocity).title("Metrocity").snippet("Levent")); marker1.showInfoWindow();
        Marker marker2 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Istinye).title("Istinye Park").snippet("Istinye/ Pınar Mh.")); marker2.showInfoWindow();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you find this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331983/multiple-info-windows-in-android-maps-api-2  Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763545/android-maps-api-v2-with-custom-markers  Or this? http://wenda.baba.io/questions/3006708/google-maps-api-v2-multiple-markers-with-their-own-infowindow.html