# Java android google maps show all markers and InfoWindows

Tags: android, google-maps

I use a api v2 google maps and I want to get on my map makers and I want to show for all markers windowsInfo I do this :

```
 for (MarkerOptions mark : markerOptionses) {
            if (mark.getPosition().latitude != 0.0)
                if (indexGooglemap >= 0) {
                    if (markerOptionses.indexOf(mark) == indexGooglemap) {
                        googleMap.addMarker(mark).showInfoWindow();
                    } else {
                        googleMap.addMarker(mark).showInfoWindow();
                    }
                } else {
                    googleMap.addMarker(mark).showInfoWindow();
                }
        }
```

But it shows only for 1 markers windows info why?

Comment: You are doing the same thing in all of your conditions. That's weird. 
Did you try to display markers regardless of their latitude ? Does it work ?

Comment: You can't show multiple info windows, but there is a workaround - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331983/multiple-info-windows-in-android-maps-api-2

Comment: You can show info window on click of a marker..That will work..

Comment: Take a look at [`IconGenerator`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/#bubbles) from Google Maps Android API Utility Library.