# Android - how to scale/move/rotate the imageviews on a imageview

Tags: android, image, scale, gesture, image-rotation

I need to implement image editor project. basically, I need to add some icons,text over an input image then export to final image.

Is there any good tutorial for this?

Comment: Just see this fully functional code

https://github.com/siddhpuraamitr/MultitouchWithDynamicAddandRemove


And Video


http://youtu.be/Jux4QnHu3dY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are searching is [android-multitouch-controller](http://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/). I have implemented in one of my application. It is working fine.

It has following facility.

1. Multi touch image scaling
2. Multi touch image zooming
3. single touch image panning

There are 3 projects. In that **"MTPhotoSortr"** is one which I used. You need to check as per your requirement.

Comment: Hi,  Is it possible to usemulti touch image scaling in emulator. thanks.

Comment: @MMakati, sorry my friend. It is not possible to do so. Emulator is not simulator. So we can not simulate it. You have to implement this in real device. :)

Comment: @ChintanRathod: Thank you! By the way do you have an idea on how to rotate image view with dotted border lines? For example the rotate image on MS powerpoint. Hope you can help me.

Comment: @MMakati, but my friend, this code also provides rotation.. have you tried it? it has multi-touch rotation. I am getting your problem. Try it first, if it doesn't full-fill your requirement i will help you.. :)

Comment: @ChintanRathod: Thank You! I will try to deploy on my phone later. Does your rotation has dotted border with anchor points?

Comment: @MMakati, no.. it has no border or anchor point. :(

Comment: @ChintanRathod: But I will try your code later. Thanks again

Comment: @ChintanRathod this code does not contain a layout. I want to use MTPhotoSortr view in another layout and then in my activity I want to set my contextview to my layout. How can I do that? thanks in advance

Comment: @ChintanRathod can u help?

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar yes, what you need to do is, you have to take a relative layout (or any other) which allow zorder layout. Your MTPhotoSortr will be upon ImageView so that you can perform pinch zoom and other operation. When you need to take out image, you can simply follow this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801116/converting-a-view-to-bitmap-without-displaying-it-in-android. So you can cretae image from your root layout which is combination of CustomView and ImageView. This way you can solve that problem.

Comment: @ChintanRathod hi, thanks for answer,how can I delete image on canvas ? I can t find the solution, can you help?

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar you can simply paint with transparent color to whole canvas. I was simply using this to provide "Eraser" functionality. :)

Comment: @ChintanRathod thanks for answer, but I need to delete one image on canvas. There are many image on canvas. So I need to set onlongclick listener to drawable object and delete just it

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar got you. actually i used above defined view and put multiple instances of that view over my relativelayout. so when user long press that, i was displaying delete dialog. but i am sorry for deleting single image in canvas, no idea. :(