# Drag And Drop on Image View

Tags: android

I have two imageview in the LinearLayout horizontally.Now I want to move one imageview at a time.But when i am moving one image view then second imageview's position is also changing. I want that at a time only one image should move.

```
private void addViewDynamically() {
        for (int i = 0; i < mTxtViewArray.length; i++) {
            mTxtViewArray[i] = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            mViewGrp[i] = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            mTxtViewArray[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            mTxtViewArray[i].setText("text " + i);

            mTxtViewArray[i].setOnTouchListener(this);
            mViewGrp[i].addView(mTxtViewArray[i]);



             mainLayout.addView(mViewGrp[i]);
        }
    }

    private void initialize() {     
        mTxtViewArray = new TextView[5];
        mViewGrp = new LinearLayout[5];
        width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        height = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        mBeforeMoveParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();

        switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            x_offset = (int) event.getX();
            y_offset = (int) event.getY();

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();

            if (x > width) {
                x = width;
            }
            if (y > height) {
                y = height;
            }

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) v
                    .getLayoutParams();
            int left = lp.leftMargin + (x - x_offset);
            int top = lp.topMargin + (y - y_offset);

            lp.leftMargin = left;
            lp.topMargin = top;

            v.setLayoutParams(lp);

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Can you post your layout code?

Comment: please tell me where i will have to write the code what i wrote ?so that you can see what i did?

Comment: Copy and paste it in your question, making sure to use the Code layout so it doesn't show up all garbled.

Comment: see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710066/android-how-to-scale-move-rotate-the-imageviews-on-a-imageview/16711222#16711222

Comment: I think it would be a better way to add the two image views with hardcoded coordinates then we can move the imageview one at a time. Apart from that solution i want to know another approach.