# Swip images is not working on multitouch in android

Tags: android, multi-touch, android-event

I have tried to make a simple android program for zoom and swip images in android as they both working on mutitouch ,I have tried for that but its not working...Can any one give good refrenece for multitouch in android?

Comment: see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710066/android-how-to-scale-move-rotate-the-imageviews-on-a-imageview/16711222#16711222

Comment: @i want some code....bro..its too theoritical...!

Comment: i heard about pinch zoom and pan.. but swip. What do that do in imageview?

Comment: Swipe you dont know? Swipe means when we multitouch image it should change...

Comment: okay.. that i know.. its gesture..isn't view pager give you such facility? swipe done by view pager and zoom by image view.?

Comment: I assume you don't wanna get these links: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/swipe-views.html or http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

what have you tried so far an what didn't work for you?!