# getMeasuredWidth returns totally wrong value

Tags: android, android-layout, view, measure

I have to measure a `View` for spacing others. I use this code for that:

```
ViewGroup view = ...;
view.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
int wrapContent = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
int specWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(wrapContent, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
view.measure(specWidth, specWidth);
int questionWidth = view.getMeasuredWidth();
```

This works as expected on an Android 4.3 emulator.

However the returned measured width on a Samsung Galaxy XCover 2 (S7710) Android 4.1.2 phone, is **16777214**...
I tried everything, masking with `View.MEASURED_SIZE_MASK`, but nothing helped.

Could you provide some help with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would help to know what's inside your viewgroup (provide xml). I just hit this same issue and solved it, I think yours is no different but let's see that layout of yours. // You don't have to mask what's returned by getMeasured*(), these values are already masked.

Comment: There is no xml. The children of the ViewGroup is dynamically instantiated and added.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Passing `WRAP_CONTENT` instead of an actual value to `makeMeasureSpec()` won't do any good, I don't think those were meant to be used together.

Use actual constraint value as first parameter (e.g. size of the parent view or dimensions of the screen) with the `MeasureSpec.AT_MOST` mode, which is basically `Math.min()` -- with arguments being the value you put in the spec and the view's desired dimension.

`MeasureSpec.EXACTLY` will make it use the spec value, `MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED` will make it use the view's desired value. So if you don't have any constraints (like if you put your view into a `ScrollView`) your option is `MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED` -- and any value as first argument.

So, *{gurus, correct me if I'm wrong}* you get `WRAP_CONTENT` behavior with any mode other than `MeasureSpec.EXACTLY`

That being said, try:

```
ViewGroup view = ...;
view.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
// Either this
int specWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parentWidth, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
// Or this
int specWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0 /* any */, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
view.measure(specWidth, specWidth);
int questionWidth = view.getMeasuredWidth();
```

**PS** Funny thing about **16777214**, take a look at the number in binary: https://www.google.ru/search?q=16777214+in+binary It's **-2** (which is the constant value of `LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT`) but with 8 most significant bits truncated with a logical operation (hence no minus), there's something in call stack of `measure()` that does this :) I wonder if this is a bug. Maybe it should be checking the argument for being negative and throwing an exception or something.

Comment: You deserve more than just an upvote.. Bounty coming your way in 23 hours.. Thanx a lot for a brilliant explanation. I've been scratching my head on this for a best part of 4 hours.

Comment: Great explanation. Really love it when people develop the answers this way. Made it easy to understand and adjust exactly for my needs. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sir, with this post you have earned your entry to Valhalla.