# Rendering a layout onto a small bitmap (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts, bitmap, metawatch

I want to inflate a layout, draw it onto a 96x96 bitmap, and send it to MetaWatch, whose 96x96 black-and-white screen has **no** gradations of gray. In fact, I have managed to do it, but I am not content with the result: ***the characters are either too large or too thin and unreadable.***

If I render the view onto a 96x96 bitmap, I get very large letters on a tiny screen:

```
public void sendView(View v) {
    Bitmap bm = createViewBitmap(v, 1, 1);
    sendLcdBitmap(bm);
    bm.recycle();
}
```

If I render the view onto a bigger bitmap and scale it back by calling `sendViewScaled(R.layout.test_layout, 1, 4)`, the scaled text does not look good. That is, it could be smaller, but it will get too thin if I make it smaller.

```
public void sendViewScaled(View v, int num, int denom) {
    Bitmap bm = createViewBitmap(v, num, denom);
    Bitmap bm2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, SCREEN_SIZE, SCREEN_SIZE, false);
    sendLcdBitmap(bm2);
    bm2.recycle();
    bm.recycle();
}
public void sendViewScaled(int id, int num, int denom) {
    sendViewScaled(inflateView(id), num, denom);
}
```

The function to convert a view into a bitmap is:

```
protected Bitmap createViewBitmap(View v, int num, int denom) {
    v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(SCREEN_SIZE*num/denom, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
             ,MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(SCREEN_SIZE*num/denom, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
             );
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    c.setDensity(Bitmap.DENSITY_NONE);//DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_xxx;
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
    v.draw(c);
    return b;

}
```

The function `sendLcdBitmap()` converts the ARGB_8888 into a single-bit bitmap using the function:

```
protected boolean isRatherWhite(int color) {
    return Color.red(color)+Color.green(color)+Color.blue(color) > 127*3;
    //return color == Color.WHITE;
}
```

So, the question is:

***I want to render a layout like `R.layout.test_layout` onto a 96x96 bitmap, B&W, no gradations of gray. How do I get a good quality?***

Relevant questions:
[Converting a view to Bitmap without displaying it in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801116/converting-a-view-to-bitmap-without-displaying-it-in-android) 
[getMeasuredWidth returns totally wrong value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586525/getmeasuredwidth-returns-totally-wrong-value) 
[How to Resize a Bitmap in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837715/how-to-resize-a-bitmap-in-android) 
[How to convert Views to bitmaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200535/how-to-convert-views-to-bitmap) 
http://www.skoumal.net/en/android-how-draw-text-bitmap

UPDATE: playing with the value used in *isRatherWhite()* helped a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is with the down scaling. You can try different algorithms like the ones mentioned here: [What is the best image downscaling algorithm (quality-wise)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384991/what-is-the-best-image-downscaling-algorithm-quality-wise)