# Caching text-view bitmap - No Text displayed

Tags: android, caching, bitmap, textview, android-bitmap

I tried to cache a text-view bitmap, to be used later, as explained in this post - [Converting a view to Bitmap without displaying it in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801116/converting-a-view-to-bitmap-without-displaying-it-in-android?lq=1).
The issue I am facing is, no text could be seen, when I tried to display the saved bitmap.
On reading SO links, I got some idea that this issue is occuring because the text-view was never really drawn at all, before I forced draw onto my bitmap/canvas, like - v.draw(c);
If that is the case, is there any solution to this issue, apart from skipping caching until the text-view was drawn atleast once.
If anyone has worked in this area before, please help!

Comment: The background set using setBackground() was visible, but the text set using setText() was not visible.