# When the user clicks a button I want the device to take a screenshot. What code should I use for this?

Tags: java, android, memory, screenshot, device

I have created a quiz app and once the user has finished the quiz an activity opens which shows a certificate with the user's achievements. I want the device to screen shot the certificate so that the user can view the screenshot in the gallery at a later date. What code should I put into my OnClickListener.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Code to take a screenshot, obviously.

Comment: (Hint: SO isn't a code-writing service. If you want help, you need a more specific question)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't need to actually take a screenshot, you likely just want to save your `View` to a bitmap. Take a look at this answer: [Converting a view to Bitmap without displaying it in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801116/converting-a-view-to-bitmap-without-displaying-it-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the current content of the browser window. Use: window.print();