# Using an xml Layout for a Google Map Marker for Android

Tags: android, layout, imageview, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to use a layout and not a drawable for my `marker` I am using with Google Maps Api 2 for an Android app.

Like this:

```
  Marker m = googleMap
                        .addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(LOC)
                                .snippet(user)
                                .title(name)
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.layout.map_marker)));
```

However, it seems this is only designed for use from `drawable` folder.

I simply what an image with a background where I can change colors based on marker type.  This is the layout I want to use:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#222"
    android:id="@+id/llMarker">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivMarker"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Pretty basic.  How can I use this as a marker? (or at least replicate the end result that I am going for?)

The documents say you can use this:

```
fromResource (int resourceId)
```

So I assumed a layout might work.

**UPDATE:**

I have taken the concept from answer below and reworked some things; this still is not working; no errors.  Just will not show image.

```
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_marker, null);

        m = googleMap
                .addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(LOC)
                        .snippet(user)
                        .title(name)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(loadBitmapFromView(v))));
```

// method

```
  public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {

        if (v.getMeasuredHeight() <= 0) {
            v.measure(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
            v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
            v.draw(c);
            return b;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Just in case, did you try the other method for getting a bitmap from the view? This may not work unless you explicitly set the bitmap's dimensions.

Comment: @matiash  Here is what I am doing now (see updated code); using the method from that link.  I actually inflated a wrong layout once on accident (a row layout from an `adapter` `getView()` method).  It TRIED to show that on the map.  So then I used the correct layout as seen above (with and without the `ImageView` and it shows NOTHING).  So I think the code is closer.  Maybe problem is xml?

Comment: If you debug, does it go inside the if statement?

Comment: Actually yes and now it is working. Not sure what happened the first time.   I will mark you correct.  I just need to figure out the part on how to change the layout dynamically (`LinearLayout` background color and `ImageView` src); but I think I can get that one working..

Comment: @KickingLettuce: How did you solve the issue: I have similar problem: Did you get a chance to solve this issue? if so how? I have a similar issue: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/25965799/xml-layout-to-map-marker

Comment: Try to make this update as an answer. This answer works pretty well

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot directly use a layout with [`BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptorFactory.html#fromResource%28int%29):

> Creates a BitmapDescriptor using the resource id of an **image**.

However, you could draw the layout into a bitmap, and then use that. You'd need to:

- Inflate the layout from xml (with a `LayoutInflater`).
- Change whatever properties you want (e.g. background color).
- Render this layout into a `Bitmap`, via `Canvas`, for example as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801116/converting-a-view-to-bitmap-without-displaying-it-in-android).
- Pass this bitmap into [`BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptorFactory.html#fromBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29).

Comment: Can you help me with a similar issue in this place: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/25965799/xml-layout-to-bitmap

Comment: Not work when the layout from xml is wrap_content, it has no height and width

Comment: how to handle click event component in view?

Comment: @matiash, I have custom view  with multiple component for marker, how to handle click event of components.How to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46622384/how-to-handle-click-event-component-of-custom-marker-in-android

Comment: @TheDevMan i get a 404 for your provided link

Answer (score 7):

The following worked for me:

```
public static MarkerOptions createMarker(Context context, LatLng point, int bedroomCount) {
    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions();
    marker.position(point);
    int px = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.map_marker_diameter);
    View markerView = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.map_circle_text, null);
    markerView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    markerView.layout(0, 0, px, px);
    markerView.buildDrawingCache();
    TextView bedNumberTextView = (TextView)markerView.findViewById(R.id.bed_num_text_view);
    Bitmap mDotMarkerBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(px, px, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mDotMarkerBitmap);
    bedNumberTextView.setText(bedroomCount);
    markerView.draw(canvas);
    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mDotMarkerBitmap));
    return marker;
}
```

map_circle_text.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bed_num_text_view"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/map_marker_diameter"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/map_marker_diameter"
    android:background="@drawable/map_circle_pin"
    tools:text="4+"
    android:textColor="@color/white">
</TextView>
```

map_circle_pin.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid
        android:color="#666666"/>

    <size
        android:width="@dimen/map_marker_diameter"
        android:height="@dimen/map_marker_diameter"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: `buildDrawingCache()` is obsolete and you don't even need it if you draw the view into a `Canvas` directly.

Answer (score 4):

Make a layout for your custom marker:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/marker_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_marker_selected" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/marker_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        tools:text="A" />

</merge>
```

Create your own `MarkerView` like this:

```
private class CustomMarkerView(root: ViewGroup,
                               text: String?,
                               isSelected: Boolean) : FrameLayout(root.context) {
    private var mImage: ImageView
    private var mTitle: TextView

    init {
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.marker_layout, this)
        mImage = findViewById(R.id.marker_image)
        mTitle = findViewById(R.id.marker_title)
        measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
        mTitle.text = text
        if (isSelected) {
            mImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_marker_selected)
        } else {
            mImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_marker_not_selected)
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you would need to get a `BitmapDescriptor` out of this custom view:

```
fun getMarkerIcon(root: ViewGroup, text: String?, isSelected: Boolean): BitmapDescriptor? {
    val markerView = CustomMarkerView(root, text, isSelected)
    markerView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
    markerView.layout(0, 0, markerView.measuredWidth, markerView.measuredHeight)
    markerView.isDrawingCacheEnabled = true
    markerView.invalidate()
    markerView.buildDrawingCache(false)
    return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(markerView.drawingCache)
}
```

Then finally, you can apply it on your marker like this:

```
fun addMarkerOnMaps() {
    val markerIcon = getMarkerIcon(
            root = activity.findViewById(R.id.activity_content_container) as ViewGroup,
            text = markerName,
            isSelected = true)

    googleMap!!.addMarker(MarkerOptions()
            .position(LatLng(coordinates.latitude, coordinates.longitude))
            .icon(markerIcon))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem and this worked for me

```
    public static Bitmap createDrawableFromView(Context context, View view) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
            .getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    view.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
    view.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels,
            displayMetrics.heightPixels);
    view.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(),
            view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;

}
```