# How to handle click event component of custom marker in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, marker

I have used xml layout to make marker .In that layout there is five buttons 'A','B','C','D','E'. I follow this [link](http://www.nasc.fr/android/android-using-layout-as-custom-marker-on-google-map-api/).I want to show different toast message click on different button like if user click on button 'A' then message will be 'you have clicked on button A'.
.[image: marker in image]How to do that? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Marker a,b;
GoogleMap mMap;
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
    .getMap();
a= mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(sc)
    .title("A")
    .snippet("A")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.a)));
b= mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(lng)
    .title("B")
    .snippet("B")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.b)));
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
        // if marker source is clicked
        if(arg0.getTitle().equals("A")){
            // display toast
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, arg0.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        // if marker source is clicked
        else if(arg0.getTitle().equals("B")){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, arg0.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: hello Shubham a and b not different marker , A,B,C,D, E are component of marker