# Is this possible to convert an entire view to Bitmap including the part over the screen?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-view

I want to generate the whole app's screen to share it. I found this question [Converting a view to Bitmap without displaying it in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801116/converting-a-view-to-bitmap-without-displaying-it-in-android)

But in my app, this may be a view higher than the screen or just a ListView, is there any way to draw whole view including the invisible part to Bitmap?

Comment: take a screeshot by programmatically !!

Comment: But screenshot only include the view on the screen, how to deal with the others?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801116/converting-a-view-to-bitmap-without-displaying-it-in-android

Comment: just another question, the method above lose all shadow of cardview, what should I do to add them back?