# Android layout screenshot from command line

Tags: android, command-line-interface, screenshot

I am trying to find a way to take a screenshot of a given XML file and generate a screenshot of it using the command line. I know there are ways to get a screenshot from Android app, as well as from IDE. I am trying to find a way to do the same from CLI.

Have been trying to read everywhere, but haven't found a way yet.

Comment: What has an xml file to do with a screen? Nothing as far as i know. So which screen do you want to shoot?

Comment: @greenapps I want to replicate the functionality from the layout preview, such that given an xml, I get a screenshot.

Comment: O a layout definition file. So you want to take a screenshot of a gui layout constructed from an xml file. Why not say so? And who/what is displaying a layout preview?

Comment: @greenapps a browser.

Comment: So NOT a layout definition file! Just any xml file. In a browser ? And why did you say 'fom Android app'? And what didn't you tell more?

Comment: @greenapps let me share an example: http://pastebin.com/BDmcfsGW and for getting screenshot from android i mean http://stackoverflow.com/a/9596132/409110. What I need is a way to do all this directly by running a command in bash. I do not want to have an android app.

Comment: Nothing makes sense the way you post your problem.  What has taking a screenshot of a view to to with the browser you mentioned? And what has a view to do with an xml file?

Comment: @greenapps An android view layout is an XML file. A screenshot is an image which is going to be displayed in the browser. I need a CLI tool to which I'll give the layout XML and the output of that command will be an image that I can show in the browser.

Comment: You post your knowledge in a terrible way. Glad you are not my teacher...