# How To Pass A Bitmap From Activity To A Fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create a bitmap from the view of my first activity and then pass that bitmap to a fragment in a ViewPager to use it as said fragment's background.

(using this to create the bitmap: [Converting a view to Bitmap without displaying it in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801116/converting-a-view-to-bitmap-without-displaying-it-in-android)).

How would I go about this?

-R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get bitmap from view by call `view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)` then using

```
Bitmap bitmap = rootView.getDrawingCache();
```

You can get Fragment by tag then call some method in fragment and set bitmap to it.

Answer (score 1):

Call a method on your fragment that takes a `Bitmap` as a parameter, if the fragment already exists. Or, use the factory pattern (static `newInstance()` method) to pass in the `Bitmap` if you are creating the fragment at the same time as you are associating the `Bitmap` with it.

However, you may want to consider having the fragment know how to load the bitmap itself from some simpler identifier (e.g., `Uri`). The fragment, by default, will be destroyed and recreated on a configuration change, and if you are using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, the fragment will be destroyed and recreated as the user navigates through the pager. This will be **far** simpler to handle if the fragment can load the image itself.