# Android Studio | Java --- Draw a Bitmap with fingers

Tags: android, android-studio, bitmap, android-canvas, android-view

For a little project I have to write an Android application for drawing a line on the screen with fingers. At the moment I use this piece of code

```
´
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   DrawingView dv ;   
   private Paint       mPaint;


   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dv = new DrawingView(this);
    setContentView(dv);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);  
}

 public class DrawingView extends View {

    public int width;
    public  int height;
    private Bitmap  mBitmap;
    private Canvas  mCanvas;
    private Path    mPath;
    private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
    Context context;
    private Paint circlePaint;
    private Path circlePath;

    public DrawingView(Context c) {
    super(c);
    context=c;
    mPath = new Path();
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);  
    circlePaint = new Paint();
    circlePath = new Path();
    circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    circlePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
    circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f); 


    }

    @Override
     protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawBitmap( mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

    canvas.drawPath( mPath,  mPaint);

    canvas.drawPath( circlePath,  circlePaint);
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
    }
    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
         mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;

        circlePath.reset();
        circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
    }
    }
    private void touch_up() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    circlePath.reset();
    // commit the path to our offscreen
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath,  mPaint);
    // kill this so we don't double draw
    mPath.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
    return true;
    }  
    }
```

}

With this I'm able to draw a line on my screen but I have no Idea how convert the painted line to a bitmap. I think I understand it wrong but I think "mBitmap" is only an empty Bitmap and the "picture" is saved in "mCanvas".

So is there any way to convert the painted line in a Bitmap?

Comment: Yes, there is a solution for this.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801116/converting-a-view-to-bitmap-without-displaying-it-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You need not create `mBitmap` or `mCanvas` for this. You could simply call `View.getDrawingCache()` to get the contents of the `View`. [More info here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache(boolean)).

But if you are planning to draw in your own bitmap, then you need to have a `mBitmap` and `mCanvas`. Follow the steps below to accomplish this:

1. Move the below lines into the constructor, since you want the bitmap and canvas creation only once.

   ```
   mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
   mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
   ```
2. In your `onDraw()` method, use the `mCanvas` to draw and not the `canvas`. Finally draw the `mBitmap` on to the view's canvas. Something like below:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       super.onDraw(canvas);

       // This will use the mCanvas and draw the `path` in the mBitmap.
       mCanvas.drawPath( mPath,  mPaint);
       mCanvas.drawPath( circlePath,  circlePaint);

       // Now once everything is drawn on mBitmap, we will draw the contents of this mBitmap onto the underlying bitmap of the View via `canvas`.
       canvas.drawBitmap( mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
   }
   ```

Always remember, every view will have an underlying bitmap (shared across). The `canvas` that you get in the `onDraw()` will help you draw stuff in the underlying bitmap. If you want to draw in your own bitmap, then you need to create a bitmap and a canvas, and draw using the canvas you created and not the one provided to you in the `onDraw()`.