# Can't convert the relative layout with all the content to an image

Tags: java, android, android-layout, bitmap

I have the Relative Layout which has a scroll view and has more than 20 textviews.
when i try to convert this layout into a bitmap it is not happening 
when i view it in an external storage it says "this file is damaged"
in gallery the image shows a black view

this is the code which i have used to convert the view to bitmap

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(Context context, View v) {

DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(dm.widthPixels, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(dm.heightPixels, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(),
        v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
v.draw(c);

return bitmap;
     }
```

I have passed the object of relative layout to loadBitmapFromView.

and
I have used this code for saving image to external storage

```
     private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {


String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
myDir.mkdirs();
Random generator = new Random();
int n = 100000;
n = generator.nextInt(n);
String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
File file = new File (myDir, fname);
if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,1000,out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
   }
```

this is my logcat

```
12-30 15:02:20.397 24825-24825/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
12-30 15:02:20.397 24825-24825/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.ResultActivity.SaveImage(ResultActivity.java:3483)
12-30 15:02:20.397 24825-24825/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.ResultActivity.onCreate(ResultActivity.java:137)
```

Comment: How you are calling SaveImage function and from where ?

Comment: i think your problem has been addressed already in other thread go here and have a look on this thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801116/converting-a-view-to-bitmap-without-displaying-it-in-android)

Comment: @Triode I am calling it from onCreate method of same class using this line - loadBitmapFromView(getApplicationContext(), v);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your createBitmap function would be returning null, You try to obtain the bitmap like below.

```
final View v = mView.findViewById(R.id.your_view_id);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( v.getMeasuredWidth(),
                v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
v.layout(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());
v.draw(c);
return b;
```

Comment: you can use (View)findViewById(R.id.your_view_id); .

Comment: @Triode it doesnt work !!!     Is there any changes in layout files like match parent and fill parent or something else

Comment: @Chirag Savsani   -    yes i did that but still the error remains and now the app has been stopped

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {   
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( 
    v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);           
     Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
     v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
     v.draw(c);   
  return b;
 }
```

and use it as

Bitmap b = loadBitmapFromView(your_layout_object);

Comment: But i was making silly mistake that i was passing the global bitmap object thats why m getting the null value