# PerformClick on ListView Return a View with height equals to 0 (Android)

Tags: android, listview, onitemclick

I have to perform a click on a list view, in onItemClick I get the bitmap of the view selected. When I manually click it's work, but when I perform the click programmatically, the height of the view equals to 0.
Here fragment of my code

```
listMedic.performItemClick(
    getViewByPosition(position), position, adapter.getItemId(position));


public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    ListElement elem = (ListElement) listMedic.getItemAtPosition(position);

    try {

        QuantityPopUp quantityPopUp = new QuantityPopUp(context);
        quantityPopUp.setImageAndPosition(getBitMapOfView(v), v, this, getResources().getString(R.string.valid_q_text_bt));
        quantityPopUp.setQuantity(Float.parseFloat(elem.getqDonn().replace(',', '.')));
        quantityPopUp.setListElementAdapter((ListElementAdapter) listMedic.getAdapter());
        quantityPopUp.setIndex(position);
        contentLayout.addView(quantityPopUp);

        popUpI = quantityPopUp;

        darkenView();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    }
} 
private Bitmap getBitMapOfView(View v){

    //récupérer la vue en tant que bitmap

    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    v.buildDrawingCache();

    return Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache(true));
}


public View getViewByPosition(int pos) {
    final int firstListItemPosition = listMedic.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listMedic.getChildCount() - 1;

    if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition ) {
        return listMedic.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listMedic);
    } else {
        final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
        return listMedic.getChildAt(childIndex);
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_element_layout, parent, false);
    }

    // récupérer l'item par sa position dans la vue
    ListElement listElement = getItem(position);

    //récupérer les éléments à remplir
    LinearLayout listElementLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listElementLayout);
    TextView denomMedic = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.denomMedic);
    TextView denom2Medic = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.denom2Medic);
    TextView qPres = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qPres);
    TextView qDonn = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qDonn);
    ImageView compIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.compIcon);

    //définir un touch listener pour afficher l'historique
    listElementLayout.setTag(position);

    //remplir les elements avec les informations
    denomMedic.setText(listElement.getDenomMedic());
    denom2Medic.setText(listElement.getDenom2Medic());
    qPres.setText(listElement.getqPres());
    qDonn.setText(listElement.getqDonn());
    compIcon.setImageDrawable(listElement.getIconBac());

    //retourner l'élément construit
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: How does your getViewByPosition() work?

Comment: Oh sorry i miss that

Comment: Please add getViewByPosition() code as part of your question (it is very hard to read inside the comment). Can you also add your getView() code?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your problem is that in some cases you are trying to get a bitmap from a `View` which has never been laid out and measured.
This happens when you are getting the View in your `getViewByPosition()` by calling `getView()` directly. It is not recommended to get a view from a list like this unless you have a very good reason.

To solve your problem you have two options:

1) Fix your `getViewByPosition()` to return a view which has already been measured and is ready to be drawn to a Bitmap (This answer can help with that: [Converting a view to Bitmap without displaying it in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801116/converting-a-view-to-bitmap-without-displaying-it-in-android)).

2) Only call `getBitMapOfView()` on views that are already drawn.

Comment: Ok. What i actually do it's add an object to my adapter, notifyDataSetChanged, and after that perform click on that row. If i understand well, the problem is that my new row is not drawn yet ? How can i wait for it ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I find an answer with the help of Doron Yakovlev-Golani. I actually add a Thread() with a sleep time. I don't know if it's the best answer but it works.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(500);
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        try {
                                            listMedic.performItemClick(
                                                    getViewByPosition(position), position, adapter.getItemId(position));
                                        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();
```