# Android - save layout as image displays black image

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap

I am generating an image on a button click. The layout used to create the image from is not currently visible inside the activity. A vector image is a background of the layout but all I see is black image.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="370dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_background">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Generating image

```
private void generateAndShareImage(){
    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_address, null);
    final TextView addressView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.address);
    addressView.setText("Test Address");

    final Bitmap cardImage = getBitmapFromView(view);
    //store image in external storage
    String savedImagePath = storeImage(cardImage);
    if(savedFilePath != null){
        scanGallery(savedImagePath);
    }
}

private void scanGallery(final String path) {
    try {
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getBaseContext(), new String[] { path },null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error scanning gallery",e.getMessage());
    }
}

private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(@NonNull  final View view){
    final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(370, 400, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `measure` and `layout` your views first:

```
int spec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
view.measure(spec, spec); 
view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
final Bitmap cardImage = getBitmapFromView(view);
```

Above code should work.

Its better to pass the dimensions of measured view in `getBitmapFromView(view, width, height)` to be used for `Bitmap.createBitmap()` instead of using hard coded values.

Check this out for other tweaks [Converting a view to Bitmap without displaying it in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801116/converting-a-view-to-bitmap-without-displaying-it-in-android)

BTW you can't use `370` as its is, if you really need to use a hard coded figure then use this instead:

```
float dp_370 = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 370, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

To understand how density independent pixels work in Android, please read:
[What is the difference between "px", "dp", "dip" and "sp" on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/what-is-the-difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-on-android)

and

https://material.io/guidelines/layout/units-measurements.html#units-measurements-scaleable-pixels-sp

**EDIT:**

Following is a working code sample that I am using to see the generated bitmap in `ImageView`:

```
final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
final View test = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null);
int spec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
test.measure(spec, spec);
int measuredWidth = test.getMeasuredWidth();
int measuredHeight = test.getMeasuredHeight();
test.layout(0, 0, measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(measuredWidth, measuredHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
test.draw(canvas);

//now show this inside an ImageView
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Thanks but it still does not work. I do not see the drawable in background and not text either. Just the color of image is now changed

Comment: @Coder I updated my answer with working sample that I am using to see the generated bitmap. May be the issue is with your `storeImage()` code.