# Obtain bitmap from GraphView withou displaying the GraphView

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap, android-graphview

I will try to explain what I need to do.

I have to print several (10) graphics in a screen and as an image is more useful for what I need to do, I need to convert the GraphView for each graph into a Bitmap.

What I am doing now is printing the GraphView on a invisible view in a layout and, after it is printed, I obtain the bitmap. It works fine but it is not the most elegant way to do this.

Does anyone know how to obtain the bitmap from a GraphView WITHOUT displaying the view?

I've tried several things ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801116/converting-a-view-to-bitmap-without-displaying-it-in-android/3036736)) but none of them worked.

Any help would be appreciated!!