# Does MPAndroidChart supports saving or export as png option?

Tags: android

Just want to know if MPAndroidChart supports export as image option while viewing the graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is no default method in library to convert chart into image . There is an open issue on library github https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/3066 .

You can try the answer suggested in the comment below .

> One thing you can do is to create a bitmap, pass it to a canvas object and call the draw method of your chart view passing this canvas object you created. Then you can save the bitmap into a JPEG or PNG file. This actually works with saving any View as an image. For more details check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801116/converting-a-view-to-bitmap-without-displaying-it-in-android)