# Add two space between TextView text

Tags: java, android, textview, drawable

I'm trying to convert `TextView` to `Drawable` to use it as a sticker in my app, but I have a problem, as you see in the picture below, The text becomes cut off from the right, to fix that I added two spaces like that:

When I add only one space like that `textview.getText()+ " "` I get this :

[image]

When I add `" " +textview.getText() + " "`,text disappears,I see only background :

[image]

after I do that, `TextView` not showing at all when I convert it to `Drawable` , here's the method to convert `TextView` to `Drawable`

```
 public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View view) {
        Bitmap createBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(createBitmap);
        view.layout(view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getRight(), view.getBottom());
        view.draw(canvas);
        return createBitmap;
    }


textView.setText(" " + editText.getText() + " ");
                    Bitmap bitmap = loadBitmapFromView(textView);
                    loadSticker(bitmap);
```

**XML :**

```
               <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:shadowColor="#fff"
                android:shadowDx="4"
                android:shadowDy="-4"
                android:shadowRadius="1"
                android:text="Your Text Here"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: do you mean padding ?

Comment: @Ticherhaz thank you for your comment, No, I didn't mean the padding

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** - 
Try using non breaking spaces maybe.

```
textView.setText((" " + editText.getText() + " ").replace(" ","\u00a0"));
```

---

Have you tried alternate methods such as,

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View view) {
        Bitmap createBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(createBitmap);
        view.layout(0, 0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
        view.draw(canvas);
        return createBitmap;
    }
```

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View view) {
        Bitmap createBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getLayoutParams().getWidth(), view.getLayoutParams().getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(createBitmap);
        view.layout(0, 0, view.getLayoutParams().getWidth(), view.getLayoutParams().getHeight());
        view.draw(canvas);
        return createBitmap;
    }
```

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View view) {
        Bitmap createBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(createBitmap);
        view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
        view.draw(canvas);
        return createBitmap;
    }
```

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View view) {
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        view.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap createBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
        return createBitmap;
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, the issue is not with the way of converting the textView to bitmap, the problem is with the TextView.getText() for some reason when I add  `" " + textview.getText().toString() + " "` the bitmap have no text

Comment: But your picture shows the text "STACKOVERFLOW" though?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have updated my post please check it to understand me clearly

Comment: @pic Try using non breaking spaces?

Comment: Hi, any updates on whether that worked?. Mark the answer as correct if it works, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this answer to convert any `View` to `Bitmap`
[Convert View to Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3036736/8577615)