# Use view without adding to view

Tags: java, android, view, drawingcache

I need to capture a view as image, but the view is not located in my activity's XML file, it's located in layout_report.xml file.

I can capture a view that is located in activity xml with the method I wrote  (method signature: `public Bitmap saveViewAsImage(View view, float pageWidth, float pageHeight`).

I tried to inflate view when the activity is created with below code:

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View layout = li.inflate(R.layout.layout_report, null, false);
saveViewAsImage(viewReport, 2600, 2800);
```

However, since view height and width was 0, I received an error. I have also tried to use fragment and inflate XML, but since I didn't call fragment `beginTransaction`, view was null.

How can I prepare a view that has width and height?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801116/converting-a-view-to-bitmap-without-displaying-it-in-android

Comment: thank you @ADM , 
`
int specWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0 /* any */, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
view.measure(specWidth, specWidth);
int viewWidth = view.getMeasuredWidth();
int viewHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();
`

height and width is not zere but is not correct too , its width is way more larger than its height

Comment: hi there @ADM, 
finally found the solution from your link, this answere [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54128490/7190108) solved m thank you for your help and directing me to right direction , since my rate is low i cant up vote you, my apology, have a nice day :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.