# I want to generate any view of android phone as an image and also share that generated image via whatsapp, skype and mail

Tags: python, java, android, api, kotlin

Here is my code can anybody suggest me what to do also NOTE: My app only supports from android 6 to 10 devices only so suggest me accordingly

```
private fun shareInvoice(){

    binding.consLayout1.isDrawingCacheEnabled = true
    binding.consLayout1.buildDrawingCache()
    binding.consLayout1.drawingCacheQuality = View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH
    val bitmap:Bitmap = binding.consLayout1.drawingCache

    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault())
    val root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absoluteFile
    val file = File(root,"/Pictures")
    val imageName = "ServiceInvoice_${businessName}_${sdf.format(System.currentTimeMillis())}"
    val myFile = File(file,imageName)

    if (myFile.exists()){
        myFile.delete()
    }

    try {
        val fos = FileOutputStream(myFile)
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, fos)
        fos.flush()
        fos.close()
        showMessage("Invoice generated successfully")
        binding.consLayout1.isDrawingCacheEnabled = false

        Log.e("INVOICE TAG", "shareInvoice:$myFile")

    }catch (e:Exception){
        Log.e("FOS TAG", "shareInvoice:$e")
    }
}
```

Comment: Here look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801116/converting-a-view-to-bitmap-without-displaying-it-in-android

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a view to Bitmap without displaying it in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801116/converting-a-view-to-bitmap-without-displaying-it-in-android)

Comment: Hello Zeeshan Ali,
Yes you are right, I want to do what you exactly said for

Answer (score 0):

Follow the method

```
private Uri saveImageExternal(Bitmap image) {
    //TODO - Should be processed in another thread
    Uri uri = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "to-share.png");
        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
        stream.close();
        uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    } catch (Execption e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IOException while trying to write file for sharing: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return uri;
}

private void shareImageUri(Uri uri){
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.setType("image/png");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

So Call

```
Uri uri  = saveImageExternal(bitmap);
shareImageUri(uri);
```

Don't Forget to add in manifest and Request The Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="18"/>
```

Comment: Hello somnath,
Thank you for your valuable reply, So i am using kotlin so getExternalFilesDir() is showing error

Comment: Use 
"val file: File = File(context?.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "to-share.png")"

Answer (score 0):

Here i get the final solution of my question if anybody wants to implement this functionality in their application
Thank you people those who posted their suggestion and interest.

This code i have tested in Android version 9,10,11 and 7

```
private fun scanFile(path: String) {
        try {
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, arrayOf(path), null) { path, uri ->
                Log.d(
                    "Tag",
                    "Scan finished. You can view the image in the gallery now."
                )
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    private fun shareInvoice(){
        val file1 = File(
            context?.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)?.path,
            Common.APP_DIRECTORY
        )
        if (!file1.exists()) {
            file1.mkdirs()
        }

        val fileName = file1.absolutePath + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg"
        val bitmap =  binding.sectionScreenShot.getBitmapFromView()

        try {
            val fos = FileOutputStream(File(fileName))
            bitmap?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos)
            fos.flush()
            fos.close()
            showMessage(getString(R.string.message_invoice_generated))
            scanFile(fileName)

            val uriForFile = FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireContext(),
                requireContext().applicationContext.packageName + ".provider",
                File(fileName))

            val share `enter code here`= Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            share.type = "image/jpg"
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriForFile)
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                delay(1000)
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Invoice"))
            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("FOS TAG", "shareInvoice:$e")
        }
    }
```