# How to set a Custom View (not an image) at the end of a multiline TextView in Android?

Tags: android, textview, android-custom-view, multiline, spannablestringbuilder

I am trying to add a custom view (the portion with red boundary will be replaced with my custom view having a 3 dots loader animation) at the end of a multi-line `TextView` in my Android app.

[image]

I know how to specifically add an `ImageView` using a `SpannableString` like this:-

```
fun addImageToEndOfTheString(text: String, drawableResourceId : Int ,context: Context) : SpannableStringBuilder {
        val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableResourceId)!!
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 98, 50)
        val rocketImageSpan = ImageSpan(drawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE)

        val ssBuilder = SpannableStringBuilder(text)

        ssBuilder.setSpan(
            rocketImageSpan,
            text.length-1,
            text.length,
            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        )

        return ssBuilder
    }
```

But the problem is I have a custom view which I want to place at the end of my `TextView`. How can I achieve that?

Note : My custom view is a subclass of `View`.

Answer (score 0):

simply: you can't.

in posted example you aren't adding `ImageView`, you are adding `ImageSpan` with just `drawable`, thats very not the same...

`View`s can't hold/host other `View`s, you have to use [`ViewGroup`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup) or some subclass

easiest way would be to make some `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation and two `View`s: `TextView` and your custom `View`. second one may have `android:visibility="gone"` and you can show it only when needed

Comment: but the problem will be my ```CustomView``` will be completely below the ```TextView```.

What if there is enough space to show my ```CustomView``` on the line on which the ```TextView``` is ending? I would like to show my ```CustomView``` in that same line.

Comment: hard, but "proper" way - your `CustomView` should contain `TextView` inside and you can get access to `textView.getPaint().getTextBounds` - measure text internally and add your `CustomView` in last line if there is a space, if not then put below. some hard math to do in here. "hacky" way would be to [convert your `CustomView` to `Drawable`/`Bitmap`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801116/converting-a-view-to-bitmap-without-displaying-it-in-android) and then you may use it in spans having only `TextView` in layout and in fact no `CustomView` at all, only its look as image in text